# Style the body during ng-view ng-animate

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I'm using `ng-view` with `ng-animate` like so:

HTML

```
<body>
  <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.view.ng-enter,
.view.ng-leave { transition: all 600ms ease-out; }

.view.ng-enter {
  position: absolute;
  top:0; left:240px;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0; }

.view.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0; }

.view.ng-leave {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 1; }

.view.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
  left: -240px; }
```

Now throughout my app there are links that will change the view. The animation of the view changing works perfectly.

I now want to add animation to the body whenever the view changes. So basically, whenever `.view.ng-view` is active, a style needs to be applied to the body, which should be removed when the view animation is no longer active. How on earth do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I have trying to find this for a while myself, it works fine if you are adding and removing classes, but with ng-view its unique in that it's transition of 2 routes,  and I haven't seen anything related to an emitter or anything. You have a few options though.

> Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fEOjoBhcPNuOBHZoU1bG?p=preview);

1) The easy answer would be to add and remove an animation with a `$timeout`, with the same duration as the css for `.view`.

```
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(e, curr, prev) {
    var body = $document.find('body');
    $animate.addClass(body, 'overlay');

    $timeout(function() {
      $animate.removeClass(body, 'overlay');
    }, 1000);
```

2) Another way is inside of the enter function you can put something in front of the done callback like, jQuery or TweenMax in this case.

```
 app.animation('.view', function() {

  return {
    enter: function(element, done) {
      TweenMax.from(element, 1, {
        color: 'red',
        onComplete: function() {
          $log.debug('done');
          done();
        }
      });
    },
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would proberly look into something like jQuery to add a class to the body when the ng-view is active.

You could also have look into the ngAnimate which is explaining to perfection:
[link to a very precise description of ngAnimate](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html)